# Biblatex: Idiom for testing contents of list field

Tags: biblatex, conditionals, etoolbox

I am creating a Biblatex bibliography style for legal citations. In one particular case, I need to format the citation (of a court decision, i.e. `jurisdiction`) differently depending on the particular institution that produced the decision. Specifically if the institution is `commission` I need to suppress printing of the `number` field, but otherwise I need to print it.

I have become familiar with the way of testing such things in other cases using `\iffieldequals`; but I can't get that to work in this case -- presumably because the `institution` field is a literal list, and I therefore need to use appropriate tests for a list (although, in practice, the `institution` field which I want to test will consist of a list with one item only: the entry `commission`).

I've tried a number of approaches: attempting to create a list of my own which consists simply of `commission` and testing for that with `\iflistequals`, attempting to use various of the list testing functions from `etoolbox`, and even `edef`ing temporary macros to compare using `\ifx`. So far, no joy -- and I think I am at or beyond the outer limits of my rather modest understanding of conditionals and expansion. In each case, the conditional is executing the false branch when I would want it to execute true.

Is there an idiom for testing whether a particular string (preferably but not essentially "held" as a macro definition, for simplicity of customisation) is present in a literal list field? I realise I could work around this by using either a custom field or a keyword instead of the `institution` field; but I'd rather keep the bibliography file more-or-less semantically correct, and `institution` is in these terms the "right" field to be testing.

Since the nearest my reason told me I was comming to a "correct" approach was using `\iflistequals` I give that as my example, in case I'm doing something wrong before I reach the test.

```
\newcommand\commission{}
\listadd{\commission}{commission}

% in bibmacro expanded by driver
\iflistequals{institution}{\commission}%
  {}
  {\printfield{number}}
```

A more complete M(N)WE follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{unique,
  title = {Title},
  number = {Number},
  institution = {commission}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bbx}
\RequireBibliographyStyle{verbose}
\newcommand{\commission}{}
\listadd{\commission}{commission}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{misc}{%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printfield{title}\setunit{\addspace}%
    \iflistequals{institution}{\commission}%
    {}
    {\printfield{number}}
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=\jobname,citestyle=verbose]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{unique}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would guess the underlying problem is that the formats of `etoolbox` internal lists and `biblatex` literal lists are different. One way to solve this is to use list item processing offered by `\printlist` via `\DeclareListFormat`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{ref1,
    title = {Title},
    number = {Number},
    institution = {commission}}
@misc{ref2,
    title = {Title},
    number = {Number},
    institution = {commissioner}}
@misc{ref3,
    title = {Title},
    number = {Number},
    institution = {school and commission}}
@misc{ref4,
    title = {Title},
    number = {Number},
    institution = {commission and school}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bbx}
\RequireBibliographyStyle{verbose}
\newcommand{\commission}{commission}
\DeclareListFormat{list:number}{%
    \ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}
    {\ifdefstring{\commission}{#1}{\listbreak}{}}
    {\ifdefstring{\commission}{#1}{}{\printfield{number}}}}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{misc}{%
    \usebibmacro{begentry}%
    \printfield{title}\setunit{\addspace}%
    \printlist[list:number]{institution}%
    \usebibmacro{finentry}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[bibstyle=\jobname,citestyle=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{ref1}, \cite{ref2}, \cite{ref3}, \cite{ref4}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, and I am considering to change my username into "Audrey's sockpuppet".

Comment: @lockstep You'd better not. My last attempt at a question was a trainwreck.

Comment: Thank you. That feels idiomatic. I was about to post my own solution (extracted by grimly watching macros trace and hacking randomly) which involved ifxing and edefing and other unattractive things; but this is so clearly superior it would be pointless.

Comment: @Paul You're welcome. I am terrible at expansion control, so I'd probably find your solution helpful.