# Page name "title page" instead of "1" in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have a title page, which should not have a real "page number". Therefore, after the title page, I set the pagecounter to 1 with

```
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

Of course, internally, the title page still has the number 1, which normally does not matter (since it does not display it).

Now I got a problem: on the title-page, I have an image and I need to give credits to the artist with a small text like "image courtesy of bla..." and I'd like to use biblatex for this, because, well... it's a source, and it's quite convienent to use. But since the internal page number where it occurs is 1, in the bibliography it appears as if it was one page 1.

Is there any way to let "(see title page)" instead of "(see page 1)" be shown? Since page is a counter, I cannot set it to a string, obviously (I tried anyway and it, of course, didn't work).

Comment: Please post the code you have tried. It is difficult for us to start without some code.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution manipulates `\thepage` and the `page` counter. The name of the title page is set in `\titlepagename`. If no further adjustments were done, the back reference in the bibliography entry of the title page image would look a bit off: "cit. on p. title page", i.e. page would be mentioned twice. To address this issue, I also do a `\renewbibmacro*{pageref}` (by modifying code from `biblatex.def`). From there, the control flows to `\printlist[list:citon]{pageref}`. The [custom list format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20088/23160) `list:citon` prints the regular back reference introduction ("cit. on p." or "cit. on pp.") or a custom string `\myciton` ("cit. on"). The latter choice is taken if a citation is made on the title page.

The solution works well if no item is cited on both the title page and some numbered page. In the latter case the back reference would look like "cit. on title page, 1". A better format might be "cit. on title page, p. 1", but implementing that might not be simple.

[image: Output of example code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=12cm,paperheight=6.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,backref=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\titlepagename}{title page}
\newcommand{\myciton}{cit. on}
\newcommand{\mybibstring}{}

\DeclareListFormat{list:citon}{%
    \ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}
    {\ifdefstring{\titlepagename}{#1}{\myciton\ppspace\listbreak}{}}
    {\ifdefstring{\titlepagename}{#1}{\myciton}{\mybibstring}\ppspace}}
\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{%
  \iflistundef{pageref}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \ifnumgreater{\value{pageref}}{1}
         {\renewcommand{\mybibstring}{\bibstring{backrefpages}}}
         {\renewcommand{\mybibstring}{\bibstring{backrefpage}}}%
       \printlist[list:citon]{pageref}
       \printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Misc{eximga,
  author = {Martin Scharrer},
  title = {example-image-a},
  howpublished = {In CTAN package \texttt{mwe}},
  year = {2012},
}
@Article{author2013,
  author = {Andy Author},
  title = {About Apparatus},
  journal = {Journal of Interesting Stuff},
  year = {2013},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\let\theoldpage\thepage
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\titlepagename}

\label{titlepage}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}

Image courtesy of \textcite{eximga}
\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage

\setcounter{page}{1}
\let\thepage\theoldpage

\phantomsection\label{firstpage}
The text starts here. Citing \textcite{author2013}.

\lipsum[1]

Citing \textcite{author2013} again.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```